Getting error Executed 'Functions.main' failed in azure logs after deployment
We are using azure functions and azure devops for deployment, Even after deploymment successful.
We are getting error as follows
[Error]   Executed 'Functions.main' (Failed, Id=5fe176d9-9244-4efa-92fd-41580ae157d0, Duration=1ms)
[time-stamp]   [Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name '' and template 'admin/warmup'
[time-stamp] [Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name 'main' and template 'api/{*segments}'
[time-stamp]  [Information]   Executing 'Functions.main' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=4aefad04-8e32-467c-ad2e-6de73bf8a826)

We are using Azure Functions and Azure DevOps for deployment. After successful deployment, we are encountering an internal server error when accessing the function.

In main/index.ts

export default async function(context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  await AzureHttpAdapter.handle(createApp, context, req);
}


in main.azure.ts

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1/education');

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS));
  app.use(RequestIdMiddleware);
  await app.init();
  return app;

Removed probable errors such as linting errors.
Created simple controller for request to return hello world
Expectation :
Even after API's maid public for a while we are getting internal server error via postman
